# Python Object Test

Tags: python

I have the following unittest questions I am trying to pass.

```
def test_map2(self):
    self.home = []
    self.home.append(Bed('Bedroom'))
    self.home.append(Sofa('Living Room'))
    self.home.append(Table('Bedroom'))

    mapping = map_the_home(self.home)
    self.assertTrue(isinstance(mapping['Bedroom'][0], Bed))  
    self.assertTrue(isinstance(mapping['Living Room'][0], Sofa))
    self.assertTrue(isinstance(mapping['Bedroom'][1], Table))
```

Every value should be a list, with one or more Furnishing subclass instances inside.

This is my current try.

```
class Furnishing(object):    
    def __init__(self, room):
        self.room = room

class Sofa(Furnishing):    
    name = 'Sofa'

class Bed(Furnishing):    
    name = 'Bed'

class Table(Furnishing):    
    name = 'Table'

def map_the_home(home):    
    results = {}

    for furnitiure in home:    
        if furnitiure.room in results:                
            results[furnitiure.room] = (results[furnitiure.room],furnitiure)    
        else:    
            results[furnitiure.room] = furnitiure        
    return results

def counter(home):    
    counter_list = {}
    for line in home:    
        if line.name in counter_list:
            print(line.room,line.name)
            counter_list[line.name] = counter_list[line.name] + 1    
        else:    
            counter_list[line.name] = 1    

    for furniture in counter_list:    
        print('{0} = {1}'.format(furniture,counter_list[furniture]))

if __name__ == "__main__":    
    home = []
    home.append(Bed('Bedroom'))
    home.append(Sofa('Living Room'))
    home.append(Table('Bedroom'))
    map_the_home(home)
    counter(home)
```

The counter is just another part but wanted to give full code. I thought I had this using dict, but as the test says I need to have every value in a list with Furnishing subclass instances inside. Any insight would be great

Comment: The line `results[furnitiure.room] = (results[furnitiure.room], furnitiure)` doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The test is expecting that the result will be like this:

```
mapping == {'Bedroom': [bed, table], 'Living Room': [sofa]}
```

Whereas you create:

```
{'Bedroom': (bed, table), 'Living Room': sofa}
```

Note that the `"Living Room"` value isn't a container, but a single `Sofa` instance.

Indeed, if you had three items of furniture in a room, e.g. adding a `Sofa` in the "Bedroom":

```
{'Bedroom': ((bed, table), sofa), 'Living Room': sofa}
```

you would keep on nesting deeper.

The minimal fix is:

```
if furniture.room in results:                
    results[furniture.room].append(furniture)    
else:    
    results[furniture.room] = [furniture]
```

Note that using a `list` and `tuple` will give the same results, as both can be indexed (although you `add` (not `append`) to tuples); I think a list is a better fit here, but your use of tuples wasn't the source of the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
def map_the_home(home):
    results = dict()
    for furniture in home:
        results.setdefault(furniture.room,[]).append(furniture)
    return results
```

Let's walk through it in pseudocode

```
home = [Bed('Bedroom'), Sofa('Living Room'), Table('Bedroom')]
map_the_home(home)
results = dict()
for each piece of furniture in the home:
    append that piece of furniture to results[furniture.room]
    if results[furniture.room] doesn't exist, make it an empty list then append
return the results
```